# backup using gzip slow

Tags: postgresql, backup, compression

We are currently backing up some schemas in Postgres using this command:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -n test_schema mydb | gzip > /data1/backup/test_chema.dmp.gz
```

And we are getting a rate of 50 Megabytes per minute, which is pretty slow, we think this could be improved.

Disk seems to be OK so is CPU.

Any thoughts on how this can get improved?

Comment: More detail is needed here before useful recommendations can be given. Is that 50mbytes/minute the output file size or the amount being read from the DB? How busy is the server at this time? Perhaps provide info read from `top` and `iotop -o` to indicate current CPU and basic IO activity. Also indicate the spec off the server. How differently does the process operate without the compression? Are the database and backup location on the same drive(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directory mode and run several parallel jobs:

```
pg_dump -F d -j 4 -h localhost -n test_schema -f /data1/backup/test_schema mydb
```

That will automatically compress the backup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, does this generate a gz file that can later be restored using the zcat command for example?

Comment: No, that will generate a directory with a "table of contents" file and a compressed file per table dumped. Yiu restore it with `pg_restore`. It is better than a plain format dump.

Comment: Thanks, I can see it's compressing at a rate of 844 MegaBytes per minute now using your suggestion, so it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the format of the output, then install and use the parallel gzip compressor, `pigz`.  After installing it, just replace 'gzip' with 'pigz' in your pipeline.  Note that this doesn't allow effective parallelization of the restoration, just of the compression of the pg_dump itself.